# Change default title on Area 51 Discussion

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

According to the [FAQ](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/faq):

> You should only ask questions about
>   proposals. You should not ask
>   questions about the site itself, like
>   bugs, feature requests, or support
>   issues. Those meta questions should be
>   asked on our meta-discussion site.

However, when you go to create a new discussion, the default meta text of `What's your bug, feature request, or meta-discussion topic?` is displayed.  This is going to cause a lot of confusion over where these meta questions should be asked.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!  Thanks for pointing this out.